# LinqToSql: Select field from list used within a query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, list

I perform a query on a table `Installation` to get a list of Ids that are needed to query a table `Product` on a different database (before you ask, it has to be this way, can't query across dbs).  Here's what the list looks like:

```
class Installation 
{
    Guid InstallationId
    Guid ProductId
}

List<Installation> installs;
```

I don't have any problems using this list for the query in to the `Product` table which looks like this:

```
var prods = (from p in context.Product 
             where installs.Select(i => i.ProductId).Contains(p.ProductId)
             select new
             {
                ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber
                // How do I get InstallationId from installs??
             }).ToList();
```

What I need to know is how I can retrieve InstallationId from the list and store it in the new list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight refactoring of Jason's answer to allow for the LinqToSql exception.

```
var products = (from product in context.Product                
                where installs.Select(i => i.ProductId).Contains(p.ProductId)
                select product).ToList()

var installedProducts = (from product in products
                         join install in installs
                         on install.ProductId equals product.ProductId
                         select new 
                         {
                             ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber,
                             InstallationId = install.InstallationId
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Creating the separate list of products was the key. I up-voted Jason, but gave you the answer since you supplied the missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

You should do a join

```
var products = (from product in context.Product
                join install in installs
                    on install.ProductId equals product.ProductId
                select new {
                    ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber
                    InstallationId = install.InstallationId
                }
               ).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, no joy: `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.`

Comment: @CAbbott: Then use your query to pull the list of products into memory (just replace your `select` with `select p`), bring the result of that query into memory with `ToList`, and then join on the resulting `List<Product>` instead of `context.Product`.